# Apply parent component css to child not in sibling component in Angular 11

Tags: css, angular, angular11, scss-lint, angular2viewencapsulation

1. i have 2 types of component, i) before login ii) after login
2. want to add 2 different css for both parent component,
3. with using **ViewEncapsulation.None** it apply in sibling component also, here is the structure of code

   ```
    - ParentComponent1
      - ChildCompoent1.1
      - ChildCompoent1.2
    - ParentComponent2
      - ChildCompoent2.1
      - ChildCompoent2.2
   ```
4. if i add CSS in **ParentComponent1** then it only apply in ChildComponent1.1 and ChildComponent1.2 not in 2.1 and 2.2, same thing apply in **ParentComponent2**

> is there any way to remove **ViewEncapsulation.None** or apply CSS only in child component not in Sibling component

Comment: You can use  `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` .

Comment: @JigneshPanchal if i am using **ViewEncapsulation.Emulated** then parent component CSS not apply to Child Component

Answer (score 0):

You can use Emulated encapsulation

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,

Similar to ViewEncapsulation.None, Angular adds the styles for this component to the head of the document, but with "scoped" styles.

Therefore, only the elements directly within this component's template will match its styles. Since the "scoped" styles from the EmulatedEncapsulationComponent are very specific, they override the global styles from the NoEncapsulationComponent.

Comment: if i am using **ViewEncapsulation.Emulated** then parent component CSS not apply in Child Component, what shold i do ?